# Conversão de string de data para datetime C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, conversão-de-tipo

Possuo um método que receberá uma string no formato "June 15, 2001", por exemplo, que equivale a data a ser comparada, eu preciso passar essa string para um DateTime, como eu faria está conversão?

Obg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [`TryParse(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) da estrutura `DateTime`:

```
DateTime data;
bool resultado = DateTime.TryParse("June 15, 2001", out data); // 6/15/2001 12:00:00 AM
```

O valor da variável `resultado` indica se a conversa foi bem sucedida ou não.

**Relativamente a cultura usada para a conversão**

Tenha atenção que por defeito a cultura usada para converter a `string` é a cultura da máquina onde o código corre. Se necessitar de indicar outra cultura (por exemplo pt-PT):

```
DateTime data;
bool resultado = DateTime.TryParse("Junho 15, 2001", new CultureInfo("pt-PT"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out data); //
```

6/15/2001 12:00:00 AM

[(Veja o primeiro exemplo no DotNetFiddle.)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hPrDd2)

[(Veja o segundo exemplo no DotNetFiddle.)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrl4q6)

Comment: Vlw, me ajudou bastante :D

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver um problema parecido com:

```
String dataString = 31/12/2000;

DateTime dataEmDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dataString,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
```