# Converter uma string dd/MM/yyy em DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Tenho um filtro de data que deve receber a a informação de um textbox e convertê-la para DateTime, para que então, eu possa comparar com outra data.
O textbox envia a data no formato dd/MM/yyyy, mas na hora de converter valores onde a data passa de 12, acontece um erro que diz que a string não pode ser reconhecida como  um DateTime.

Já olhei vários sites e respostas similares neste e em outros, mas nada dá certo.

Se não houver um jeito simples, vou ter que apelar para formatar a string antes de passar pro date e vai na gambiarra mesmo.

#### Código

```
List<PainelFormularioMetodologia> PesquisaDataMaxima(List<PainelFormularioMetodologia> listaPesquisa)
    {
        List<PainelFormularioMetodologia> listaRetorno = new List<PainelFormularioMetodologia>();

        //O erro acontece aqui

        DateTime dataFim = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime dataIni = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       /////////////////////

        if (dataFim < dataIni)
            Util.Alert("Data final é menor que Data inicial.");

        foreach (PainelFormularioMetodologia item in listaPesquisa)
        {                
            if (item.Dt_ModificaProcesso_data <= dataFim)
                listaRetorno.Add(item);
        }

        if (listaRetorno.Count == 0)
            Util.Alert("Verifique o filtro: Modificado em");

        return listaRetorno;            
    }
```

#### Erro

> [FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string is not
>   supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funcionou como:

```
DateTime dataFim = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
DateTime dataIni = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
```

Comment: Poste o que como a data é inserida e qual erro tem gerado por favor.

Comment: Postei agora, quando o campo está que nem no Início, a pesquisa é feita normalmente, mas quando passo do 12 o bicho pega.

Comment: Tenta no lugar do CultureInfo.InvariantCulture tenta usar new CultureInfo("en-US")

Comment: Como você pode ver neste link https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx, o comando `Converte a representação de cadeia de caracteres especificada de uma data e hora para sua DateTime equivalente usando o formato especificado e as informações de formato específicas da cultura`. Então a sua data deve estar vindo com hora ou algo a mais, por isto o erro. O segundo parametro da função tem que ser o formato que a sua data está agora e não o formato que ela vai ficar.

Comment: Então o segundo parâmetro deve ficar MM/dd/yyyy? Também chequei o que está vindo dos txtDataFim e Inicio e não está vindo hora, só a data como dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Tenta substituir o `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` por `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")`

Comment: @JoaoRezende como está vindo o valor de `txtDataInicio` e `txtDataFim`

Comment: @JoaoRezende fiz um exemplo rápido https://dotnetfiddle.net/J0cVBo

Comment: Estão vindo daquele jeito mesmo: DataInicio: 12/04/2014 e Datafim: 30/04/2016

Comment: To testando sua resposta, legal o exemplo, então deveria estar certo o que eu fiz.

Comment: Também não foi reconhecido se eu por o dia maior que 12, deve estar querendo q a string venha como MM/dd/yyyy. Vou tentar substituir pelo createspecificculture

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado Thiago, Marlon e Richard! O createSpecificCulture deu certo, vou editar e postar o jeito certo caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida.

Comment: @JoaoRezende Poste uma resposta de como conseguiu. Pode ajudar outra pessoa também.

Comment: TL;DR; Essa pergunta não é duplicata [desta outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68247/18246)?

Answer (score 6):

Tenta substituir o `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` por `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")` – Richard Dias

Funcionou e ficou assim:

```
DateTime dataFim = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataFim.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
DateTime dataIni = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataInicio.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"));
```

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.

Answer (score -3):

Tente fazer isso:

```
DateTime data = DateTime.MinValue;

try {
 data = DateTime.Parse(dataString);
} catch{ data = DateTime.MinValue}

if(data.CompareTo(DateTime.MinValue) != 0)
  //data correta
else
  //data incorreta
```

Comment: Utilizar um Try catch para resolver esse tipo de problema gera um processamento desnecessário.